# Rails order product price ascending and descending by their minimum value has_many relation

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to **order** my products by their **price** **ascending** and **descending**, but depending on the minimum value.

```
products `has_many` product_prices through product_offers.
```

I am using `@products.includes(:product_offers).includes(:product_prices).where(...).order("product_prices.price ASC")` or `DESC` 
function of rails, but I need to order the products regarding their minimum prices. I then want to loop like this:

```
<% for @product in @products %>
 <%=@product.product_prices.minimum("price").first%>
<% end %>
```

Thats why `@products` has to have the right order. It is giving me always the same order. What am I doing wrong? The problem is lets say product 1 is in a price range of 10$ - 50$ and product 2 from 20$ - 40$. if I use the order `ASC` function it would show product 1 then product 2. If i use the order `DESC` function it would show product 1 then product 2, because 50$>40$, but what I want is 20$> 10$ (Minimums) product 2 then product 1.

Thank you very much for help!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest adding a scope to the product_prices to identify the price that is the minimum for the product.

```
def self.minimum_for_product
  where("product_prices.price = (select min(pp.price)
                                   from product_prices pp
                                  where pp.product_id = product_prices.product_id")
end
```

Then you can define in Product:

```
has_one :minimum_price, -> {merge(ProductPrice.minimum_for_product)}, :class_name => "ProductPrice"
```

This will let you:

```
ProductPrice.join(:minimum_price).
             references(:minimum_price).
             order("product_prices.price")
```

Thus the identification of the minimum prices and the ordering or products is carried out in a single SQL statement, which will be faster and use fewer resources that a Rails-based sort.

Comment: Hi, I will try this solution. Do I have to put `:minimum_price` into  `attr_accessible` line?

Comment: No, attr_accessible only controls whether the attributes on the instance can be set by passing a hash to update_attributes, so it's entirely to do with setting values, not getting them.

Comment: Ok, if I use the has_one line in my model, I `get wrong number of arguments (3 for 1..2)` error.